# error LNK2001: while trying to install requirements.txt

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to use "pip3 install -r requirements.txt" and the feed back turn out to be a bunch of errors, indicates that I have link questions, I don't know how to deal with this problem, should I re-install my python 3?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPiIG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQEEU.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)